# Is it possible to find my coordinates (lat + long) in R?

Tags: r, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Is there a way to use R to show my own geographic coordinates (latitude/longitude)? I know that there are ways to do this in Shiny, but I'd like to be able to do so in RStudio itself.

Comment: Could you add a link to *ways to do this in Shiny,*?

Comment: dario: you can implement it by including some javascript in your shiny app. The code to do so (you don't need to write any of the javascript itself, you can copy and paste) can be found here: https://github.com/AugustT/shiny_geolocation

Comment: Ah, ok i see. so it' s a rather JS than shiny that does the geolocation... One way to get coordinates without shiny server would be to launch a custom html file where you can use the JS functionality. Another solution I had success with in the past is to retrieve the public IP and then use one of the available IP to geolocation websites. It's not always super accurate but it worked well for my purposes (your mileage might differ)

Comment: Just to clarify: did you do this in RStudio? I'm developing a package, and the user location is important to identify.

Comment: No, i didn't use RStudio to write the code. Or use the functions from the rstudioapi... But the functions work of course also when called from an RStudio console. Or any other IDE.The only caveat is that the function relies on IP address to guess the location (which does not always work) and needs internet access to resolve the ip (but I think there are databases around where we could do this lookup locally)... I just needed a way for my  package to suggest some settings, but they were easily corrected by the user, so the sometimes bad geo guessing was no issue..